# Avoid distortring squares/circles in Matplotlib figure with fixed figsize

Tags: python, matplotlib

In a Matplotlib figure with aspect ratio `12:5`, a square is drawn on `ax` and 4 circles on `ax2`.  The 4 circles are then redrawn with different colors.

However, the square looks like a rectangle, and the circles look like ellipses.

[image]
Is it possible to maintain the figure aspect ratio without distorting the square and circles?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def draw():
    
    ax.set_xlim(-1, 7)
    ax.set_ylim(-1, 7)
    
    ax2.set_xlim(-1, 7)
    ax2.set_ylim(-1, 7)
    ax2.set_xticks([])
    ax2.set_yticks([])

    p = plt.Rectangle((0,0), 5, 5)
    ax.add_patch(p)

    ax2.add_patch(plt.Circle((0,0), 0.1, color="r"))
    ax2.add_patch(plt.Circle((0,5), 0.1, color="r"))
    ax2.add_patch(plt.Circle((5,0), 0.1, color="r"))
    ax2.add_patch(plt.Circle((5,5), 0.1, color="r"))
    
def redraw():
    ax2.clear()

    ax2.set_xticks([])
    ax2.set_yticks([])
    ax2.set_xlim(-1, 7)
    ax2.set_ylim(-1, 7)

    ax2.add_patch(plt.Circle((0,0), 0.1, color="g"))
    ax2.add_patch(plt.Circle((0,5), 0.1, color="r"))
    ax2.add_patch(plt.Circle((5,0), 0.1, color="g"))
    ax2.add_patch(plt.Circle((5,5), 0.1, color="r"))
    
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 5)) # needs to be non-square
ax2 = ax.twinx().twiny()
draw()
redraw()
```

Comment: You can use `ax.set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')` to update the x and y limits for an undistorted plot area. [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want no distortion, you need to change the limits on the x axis. You can change the xlimit according to the aspect ratio 12:5 = 2.4:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def draw():

    ax.set_xlim(-1, 7 * 2.4)
    ax.set_ylim(-1, 7)

    ax2.set_xlim(-1, 7 * 2.4)
    ax2.set_ylim(-1, 7)
    ax2.set_xticks([])
    ax2.set_yticks([])

    p = plt.Rectangle((0, 0), 5, 5)
    ax.add_patch(p)

    ax2.add_patch(plt.Circle((0, 0), 0.1, color="r"))
    ax2.add_patch(plt.Circle((0, 5), 0.1, color="r"))
    ax2.add_patch(plt.Circle((5, 0), 0.1, color="r"))
    ax2.add_patch(plt.Circle((5, 5), 0.1, color="r"))


def redraw():
    ax2.clear()

    ax2.set_xticks([])
    ax2.set_yticks([])
    ax2.set_xlim(-1, 7 * 2.4)
    ax2.set_ylim(-1, 7)

    ax2.add_patch(plt.Circle((0, 0), 0.1, color="g"))
    ax2.add_patch(plt.Circle((0, 5), 0.1, color="r"))
    ax2.add_patch(plt.Circle((5, 0), 0.1, color="g"))
    ax2.add_patch(plt.Circle((5, 5), 0.1, color="r"))


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 5))  # needs to be non-square
ax2 = ax.twinx().twiny()
draw()
redraw()
```

This yields the following [image: figure]

Comment: Here, you suppose that the axes have the same aspect ratio as the figure (`12/5`).  Depending on what else is on the plot, and the size of titles and labels (or even multiple subplots), the aspect ratio will be different.